# Finding roots of an equation

Tags: c++

I am trying to define an algorithm in C++ but there is an error that I can't understand
I want my algorithm to find the roots of an equation of the second degree, and give me the solution as a list...

I already defined `nbRacines` which gives the number of the roots and it is working correctly.
So this is my definition...

```
list<float> Racines (float a,float b, float c)
{
    float discr=b*b-4*a*c;
    float li={};

    if (nbRacines(a,b,c)==2)
    {
        li={((-b-sqrt(discr)/2*a),((-b-sqrt(discr)/2*a)))};
    }

    if (nbRacines(a,b,c)==1)
    {
        li={(-b/2*a)};
    }

    return li;
}
```

And it gives this error...

```
$ g++ -Wall -pedantic -std=c++0x -c -Werror definitionsFonctions.cpp
definitionsFonctions.cpp: In function ‘std::__cxx11::list<float> 
Racines(float, float, float)’:
`definitionsFonctions.cpp:269:10: error: could not convert ‘li’ from ‘float’ to 
‘std::__cxx11::list<float>’
   return li;
          ^~
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'definitionsFonctions.o' failed
make: *** [definitionsFonctions.o] Error 1
```

Comment: `float li={};` creates a `float`, not a `list`.

Comment: how can i fix it?

Comment: `float li={};` means `float li=0;`. You probably want `list<float> li;` instead. (Note that I only mentioned `std::list` because you used it as a return type. I'd say `std::vector` should be used instead.)

Comment: Be aware of [Catasrophic cancelation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance).

Comment: Note: formula for the roots is not  correct...

Comment: To go further on @Damien's comment, there is a serious bracket problem. Eg. `-b/2*a` is different from `-b / (2*a)`, the same goes for the square roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an object declared `float li` and you try to use it as the return value of your function. You also try to assign a sequence of values to it. This won't work, and will use `operator,` instead of what you want. To fix it, return the list directly:

```
std::vector<float> Racines (float a, float b, float c)
{
    float discr=b*b-4*a*c;

    switch(nbRacines(a,b,c))
    {
        case 2: return {-b-sqrt(discr)/2*a, -b-sqrt(discr)/2*a};
        case 1: return {-b/2*a};
        throw std::logic_error("quadratic equations have two roots");
    }
}
```

Arithmetic note 1: all quadratic equations have two roots, some just have two *equal* roots

Arithmetic note 2: I think you mean to return `-b+sqrt(discr)/2*a` as one of the elements of your two element list

Style note: `std::vector` is a much better default container than `std::list`. You should only use `list` when you need its properties (lack of reference invalidation).

Comment: Okay but i am really new to this and i cant say that i understand what u explained... so by changing float li={}; to list<float> li; my algoritme worked but when i am trying to find roots of an equation which has 1 roots it gives me the right answer but when i try to find roots of an equation which has 2 roots it gives me the wrong answer and it gives me only one answer

Comment: note: yes i  meant -b+sqrt(discr)/2*a

Comment: and to be specific i didnt understand the part when u talked about vector and why i shouldnt use list because i didnt learn vecteurs yet

Comment: The meaning of `((-b-sqrt(discr)/2*a),((-b-sqrt(discr)/2*a)))` is **exactly the same as** `-b-sqrt(discr)/2*a`, because `,` in this context evaluates the left, discards the result, then evaluates the right. C++ has the "as-if" rule, which basically says that the compiler is allowed to omit parts of the program that have no effect, like calculating a number and discarding it.

Comment: You should remove the `()`, as in my answer

Comment: okay it is working now thank you very much